# How to fade up from black over more than one clip?

Tags: premiere, transitions

I would like to open my presentation with a fade up from black who's duration spans more than one clip.  The normal transitions don't seem to allow me to cross the clip bounday.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You could simply add a black clip above that fades out.

Comment: Thanks, that helps!